# Slow writes to firestore db

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, openai-api

I have created an firebase function that runs express application on top the app, there is this particular function in my application that get openai response as stream and writes the response to firestore-database this works perfectly fine on when I run locally however it is prohibitively slow when deployed I even tried to reduce the number of writes to firestore but its still does not help

```js
const { db } = require("../database/firebasedb");

const {doc , getDoc, setDoc} = require("firebase/firestore")

require("dotenv").config();
const { OpenAIApi, Configuration } = require("openai");


const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

module.exports = {

    gptReponseToFirestore: async (clientDetails, chatDetails) => {
        console.log({ clientDetails: JSON.stringify(clientDetails), chatDetails: JSON.stringify(chatDetails)});


        const {userId, chatId} = clientDetails;
        const chatReferencPath = `users/${userId}/chats/${chatId}/`;
        const chatRef = doc(db, chatReferencPath);
        const chatHistory = (await getDoc(chatRef)).data();
        console.log({quetGPT: { ChatReferencePaht: chatReferencPath, chatHistory: JSON.stringify(chatHistory)}})


        const messagesIndex = chatHistory.messages.length - 1



        const question = chatDetails.userInput;
        let currentToken = ""
        let completionText = ""
        let tokenCounter = 0


        const { data } = await openai.createChatCompletion({
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            n: 1,
            temperature: 0.9,
            stream: true,
            messages: [{ role: "user", content: question }]
        }, {
            responseType: 'stream'
        });

        data.on('data',  (text) => {

            const lines = text.toString().split('\n').filter(line => line.trim() !== '');

            for (const line of lines) {
                const message = line.replace(/^data: /, '');
                if (message === '[DONE]') {
                    console.log("response stream ended.")
                    chatHistory.messages[messagesIndex].a = completionText;
                    setDoc(chatRef, chatHistory)
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    const { choices } = JSON.parse(message);

                    currentToken = choices[0].delta.content;
                    if (currentToken !== undefined) {
                        if (tokenCounter % 25 == 0) {

                            console.log(currentToken)
                            completionText = completionText.concat(currentToken.toString());
                            chatHistory.messages[messagesIndex].a = completionText;
                            setDoc(chatRef, chatHistory, {merge: true})
                        } else  {

                            completionText = completionText.concat(currentToken.toString());
                        }
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
            // console.log(tokenCounter)
            tokenCounter++
        });

        data.on('close', () => {
            console.log("close");

        });

        data.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
        return;

    }
}
```

this is structure of document that is updated what is withing collection chats

```json
{
   "messages" : [
      {
        "a": "this is a reply that is appended by function",   // this a answer
        "q": "this question appended already by frontend",     //this is answer
      },
      {
        "a": "this is reply",
        "q": "this question appended already by frontend",
      },


  ]
}
```

So I was trying to write and openai stream data to firestore but its increabilly slow, I viewed logs the rate a received characters from openai is very fast yet the firestore-db is updated after much delay , what can I your suggestion for me to increase speed of writes and reduced delay in making those text  available in firestore